# How can I change an ArrayList that is returned to a method? - Java

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

That is the code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        changeList();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(example().toArray()));
    }

    public static void changeList() {
        example().set(2, "Hi!");
    }

    public static List<String> example () {

        String str = new String("word1|word2|word3|word4|word5");

        return Arrays.asList(str.split("\\|"));
    }
}
```

I want the ArrayList to be like this: `[word1, word2, Hi!, word4, word5]`
But it doesn't change... It prints`[word1, word2, word3, word4, word5]`

Is it even possible to change it that way?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: move the return of example() into a variable....

Comment: It works for me. What do you mean by "it does not change"? can you provide a full running example that shows the problem?

Comment: Please give a complete example. You should include a `main()` method which calls this `example()` method and then does whatever else you want. Also add `System.out.println()` calls and show what the results are. Then explain what you want your program to do differently.

Comment: Post the full code. Normally setting an item like that would work. So clearly you're missing the key part of the code that introduces a bug.

Comment: @Dimezis I edited it!

Comment: You are creating 2 lists. Modifying first, but printing a completely different one.

Comment: the changes from `changeList()` are not recorded

Comment: But is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `example` gives a brand new `List` each time it's called. When you create the list in `changeList`, it's a different `List` than the one you create in `main`, and changes made to one `List` won't affect another.

One way to fix this is to:

1. Have the `changeList` method do what it says: take in a `List` (rather than producing one from scratch) and change that `List`.
2. Have the `main` method pass in the `List` to `changeList`.

```java
public static void main(String[]args) {
    List<String> list = example();
    changeList(list);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
}

public static void changeList(List<String> list) {
    list.set(2, "Hi!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But it doesn't change... Is it even possible to change it that way?

yes, you change the list but you lost the ref of the returned collection since the method `public E set(int index, E element)` returns E and not the list itself.. see the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E))

as I said, move the return of example() into a variable that you can manipulate...

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    List<String> retVal = example();
    System.out.println(retVal);
    retVal.set(2, "Hi!");
    System.out.println(retVal);
}

public static List<String> example () {
    String str = new String("word1|word2|word3|word4|word5");
    return Arrays.asList(str.split("\\|"));
}
```

Comment: Youre right! But I want to change the value in the method, because I use the methed several times...

Comment: @Andy What do you mean by that? Can you explain in words the entire problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(changeList().toArray()));
    }

    public static List<String>  changeList() {
        List<String> list = example();
        list.set(2, "Hi!");
        return list;
    }

    public static List<String> example () {

        String str = new String("word1|word2|word3|word4|word5");

        return Arrays.asList(str.split("\\|"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's step through your code one line at a time to understand what it is doing:

```
 public static void main(String[]args) {
    changeList();
```

This calls the `changeList()` method:

```
public static void changeList() {
    example().set(2, "Hi!");
```

First call `example()`:

```
public static List<String> example () {
    String str = new String("word1|word2|word3|word4|word5");
    return Arrays.asList(str.split("\\|"));
}
```

This creates a new `List` and returns it back to `changeList()`:

```
example().set(2, "Hi!");
```

Now we modify the returned `List` by setting the element at index 2 to `"Hi!"`. However, the modified list is immediately discarded because you have no reference to it any more.

Then we return back to main:

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(example().toArray()));
```

Now we call example again:

```
public static List<String> example () {
    String str = new String("word1|word2|word3|word4|word5");
    return Arrays.asList(str.split("\\|"));
}
```

This creates a **new `List`**. This new list is in no way related to the list that was created when we called `example()` the previous time.

If you want to keep the same list, you need to assign it to a reference in `changeList()` and then return it:

```
public static void changeList() {
    List<String> theList = example();
    theList.set(2, "Hi!");
    return theList;
}
```

Now main() needs to save a reference to the list returned by `changeList()`:

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
    List<String> mainList = changeList();

    System.out.println(mainList);
}
```

(Note: You can print the `List` directly. Your original version is much more complicated than necessary.)